# Is the sheaf of locally constant functions flasque?

Tags: general-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

Quick question, is the sheaf of locally constant functions flasque?

Comment: No, since otherwise the whole subject of ordinary cohomology theory would be trivial: The sheaf of locally constant functions is also called "the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$". If it were flasque, then sheaf cohomology with values in $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$ would be trivial in degress $> 0$, since flasque sheaves are acyclic. But for nice spaces, for instance manifolds, sheaf cohomology with values in $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the same as ordinary $\mathbb{R}$-valued cohomology (singular or de Rham).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, take two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ lying in the same connected component $X_0$ of the entire space $X$.  Then define a section on $U \cup V$ by the function being $0$ on $U$ and 1 on $V$.  Then this section cannot extend to $X$.

Comment: That's so weird you know. Take a topological space $X$, let $S$ be the Borel sigma-algebra generated by the topology, a measurable function can always be extended to a measurable function outside its original domain, so if we have a locally constant function defined on a subset $A$, we can extend it to a function with value 0 outside of $A$, under this transformation, the locally constant function would stay locally constant no? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not sure I know exactly what you're saying but I think the extension will be measurable but not locally constant.  In the counterexample I gave you can extend that function to all of $X$ in many ways and it will be measurable but no longer locally constant (indeed it will no longer be continuous).

Comment: Thanks Eric, now check this out: Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite-dimensional topological vector spaces. Let $F$ be the sheaf of $Y$-valued locally constant functions. Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be their Borel sigma-algebras respectivelly. Now since every measurable function $f$ defined on a measurable subset $A$ of a measurable space can be extended to a measurable function $f'$ on $X\A$ by defining it to be 0 (hence linear) on $X\A$, this means $f'$ is continuous as linear maps between finite-dimensional TVSs are continuous, so the sheaf of locally constant functions on $X$ is flasque? in this case no?

Comment: Also worth noting: in the Zariski topology, generally open sets are dense, you can't find disjoint opens, and the sheaf of constant functions *is* flasque.

Comment: In the Zariski topology on an irreducible space, I meant.

Answer (score 0):

This is true if your space is irreducible. [Kedlaya gives the example](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-726-algebraic-geometry-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_726s09_lec17_sheafcoh.pdf) of $U = \mathbf{R} - \{0\}$ sitting inside of $\mathbf{R}$ with the Euclidean topology, showing that a constant sheaf need not be flasque in general.